# How to distinguish color int from color resource

Tags: android, type-safety

I am writing a method that take in color as an integer value (e.g. [Color.BLACK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#BLACK)).

```
void justDoIt(int color) {}
```

Had it been a color resource (e.g. [R.color.black](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color.html#black)), I would have used [@ColorRes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/ColorRes.html) annotation to be explicit about the type of integer.

```
void justDoIt(@ColorRes int colorResId) {}
```

Is there a way to do something similar for int color?

**TL;DR**: How to ensure that an int param is a int color and not a color resource (opposite of @ColorRes)

Comment: Don't get it can you just explain the question with other words?

Comment: I think omitting the annotation indicates just that, but I see your point, one are left to assume it's integer value that is expected. I'd say better avoid res id - it's prone to cause confusion. I'd never expect to use a color res id rather than integer value.

Comment: @Skizo only reason for being explicit is so that someone else may learn something from it. I'll add TL;DR anyway. Thanks.

Comment: The tag android-annotations is for the library AndroidAnnotations (https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations). This answer is not about AA so please, remove this tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the annotation [`@ColorInt`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/ColorInt.html) for this purpose.